# How to calculate x,y position of 3D points?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, coordinate-systems, vector-analysis, projective-geometry

[image]

I have points in 3D system like this

$$p1=(2,3,4)$$
$$p2=(3,5,5)$$

Here I would like draw point $p1$ and $p2$ in $2D$ view.

Project type = orthographic.
Coordinate system = Cartesian

X- axis, min = 2, max=9
y-axis min=2, max=12
z-axis min=1, max=10

Basically I would like draw $3D$ points in $2D$ view.(using Cartesian coordinate system)

Please help me find an answer for the following question.

1) how can convert $3D$ points $(p1, p2)$ to $2D$ points. What is the formula for this?

I cann't upload images yet, as I need at least 10 reputation as per the forum rules.

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: If you need of 10 of reputation I will give one vote.

Comment: Answer would be great help than Vote!

Comment: You need to specify which plane you want the points projected onto.

Comment: To do an orthographic projection you need to specify a plane onto which the original points are projected. The plane is usually described by a 3D vector. A projection onto the x-y plane would use $(0,0,1)$, another 'perspective-like' projection would be $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: when it is rotatable, it is difficult identify which plane is in the eye view(visible). am telling in perspective of programming

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the orientation of the plane you are projecting onto.  The easiest examples are planes perpendicular to one of the axes.  So if you project onto a plane perpendicular to $z$, your get $p1=(2,3), p2=(3,5)$

Comment: What if rectangle is rotatable?

Comment: Then you must rotate the plane using standard rotation matrices, and project onto the resulting plane.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, orthographic is parallel projection.

Pick a normalized direction $h \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (ie, $\|h\| = 1$). Then you will be projecting onto the plane $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | h^T x = 0\}$. An example would be $h = (0,0,1)$ which would be a plan view.

Then the projection $P: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $P(x) = (I - h h^T) x = x - \langle h, x \rangle h$.

For example, if $h = (0,0,1)$, then $P((x,y,z)) = (x,y,0)$. (This is essentially the same as Ross' example.)

Comment: Help me to solve the equation by using above points.

Comment: @flex: You haven't given enough information to uniquely solve the problem.

Comment: could u pleas tell me, What other information is missing?

Comment: @flex:  the missing information is the plane you want to project onto.  It could be the $xy$ plane, as in my example.  It could be the $yz$ plane.  It could be the plane perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ or any other.  Think of looking at your box from various angles.  We need to specify the viewpoint.

Comment: Ok, lets Assume XY plane

Comment: That is the example I gave above. It is also the same as given by Ross below.